# How to allow users to modify front end menus?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am writing a backend/admin area for a website.  The users want the ability to modify their menu's on the website.

- These menus can be hierachical no more than 3 levels deep.
- Do you allow users to do this?
- How do you store the hierarchy?
- How do you programmatically display the menu?
- How do you make it easy for users to create hierarchies - some sort of jQuery drag/drop?

Look forward to your replies.

Answer (score 1):

**Do you allow users to do this?**
No, but admins on some sites. (Though none built with MVC or jQuery.)

**How do you store the heirarchy?**
In a table, with a parent-field.

**How do you programmatically display the menu?**
I iterate throught the table and output HTML.

**How do you make it easy for users to create heirarchies - some sort of jQuery drag/drop?**
Make menu-editing page, where you output the menu in the content-area of your page, and then use something like jQuery sortable plugin to move things around, and custom code to delete and insert new items.

Comment: The users allowed to do this will be admins. My site is written in MVC, what do propose is better to handle this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

These menus can be heirachical no more than 3 levels deep. 
OK

Do you allow users to do this? 
Not generally, but I can see cases where this might be useful.

How do you store the heirarchy? 
In a table in the database, by user ID.  You also need a column in the table to implement the hierarchy, and another table to contain the menu options and base URLs.

How do you programmatically display the menu?
That's a tricky one.  You have to find a way to push the menu hierarchy into the page from the controller.  JSON seems a likely candidate.  Something from [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) should be able to pick up this JSON and render a menu for you.

How do you make it easy for users to create heirarchies - some sort of jQuery drag/drop? 
jQuery UI has a Drag-drop feature.

Good Luck!

Comment: "You have to find a way to push the menu hierarchy into the page from the controller" - Any ideas?

Comment: Jon, see my other post below.

Answer (score 0):

Jon,

Have a look at this link for additional ideas:

http://www.webappers.com/2007/09/05/smooth-and-clean-fastfind-menu-jquery-plugin/

> FastFind Menu Script is a javascript
>   menu created by ActiveSpotLight under
>   the BSD License. It pulls a content
>   feed as data to populate the menu,
>   this can be static or dynamic. The
>   version they use internally uses
>   JSON/XML as data feeds. This script
>   allows for nested menus, based on
>   dynamic Ajax responses. The menu can
>   also be dragged/dropped by using the
>   jQuery Interface Library.

Answer (score -1):

You ask a lot of questions man ;)

You obviously know about jQuery, hence the tag... jQuery will make your life so easy. Please take a look at jQuery UI, that will solve all your problems: http://jqueryui.com/